# Cannot Unserialize an object array in php

Tags: php, serialization

I have an array of Shift objects that I'm working with in PHP. I need to store these objects within a database. I'm working on a function that will add shifts to the database:

```
$Serialized_S = get_option('MasterShiftString');
$MasterShiftArray = unserialize($Serialized_S);

if(!$MasterShiftArray)
{
    echo "MasterShiftArray returns false";
}//end if

echo "Serialized_S:";
print_r($Serialized_S); 
echo "<br />MasterShiftString:";
print_r($MasterShiftString); 
echo "<br />end<br />"; 



if(!is_array($MasterShiftArray))
{
    echo "MasterShiftArray is not an Array....";
    $MasterShiftArray = array($last_monday_from_date => "");

}//end if
else
{


}//end else 

$WeekShiftArray = $MasterShiftArray;

array_push($WeekShiftArray, $CurrentShift);         

$MasterShiftArray[$last_monday_from_date] = $WeekShiftArray;

$Serialized_s = serialize($MasterShiftArray);

update_option('MasterShiftArray', $Serialized_s);
```

Of course what I'm getting when I execute this is:

```
last_monday_from_date: 1260777600
MasterShiftArray returns falseSerialized_S:admin,resource,2,1;admin,resource,2,1;admin,resource,2,1;admin,resource,2,1;
MasterShiftString:
end
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried the base64 encoding, but that doesn't do anything to help.
    MasterShiftArray is not an Array....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
admin,resource,2,1;admin,resource,2,1;admin,resource,2,1;admin,resource,2,1
```

looks nothing at all like a PHP serialized array, that's your problem.  Garbage in = garbage out.

Assuming that's the data format you need to deal with, look into using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to break it into an array on ';', then explode each member of that array on ','.

Comment: OMG ... I'm sorry .... I feel like a complete idiot now... I put in the wrong var.